# Error in sqlAlchemy in flask in line " Math_title = request.form('title')"

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

```
@app.route('/posts',methods=['GET','POST'])


def scratc():


    if request.method == 'POST':

        Math_title = request.form('title')

        Math_content = request.form('content')
        new_post = Math(title=Math_title, content=Math_content, author='Ayush')
        db.session.add(new_post)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect('/posts')
    else:
        all_posts=Math.query.all()
        return render_template('scratch.html',posts=all_posts)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.r
```

The error I am getting is:

> TypeError: 'ImmutableMultiDict' object is not callable

Comment: Please provide the full traceback (line number where the error occurs).

Answer (score 0):

Flask's [`Request.form`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.form) is an instance of a [`werkzeug.MultiDict`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict). From the `MultiDict` docs:

> A MultiDict is a dictionary subclass... MultiDict implements all standard dictionary methods.

So, you can use `request.form["title"]` and `request.form["content"]`, or `request.form.get("title")` and `"request.form.get("content")` depending on how you prefer to manage missing keys in the submitted form data.